# How to store 2 tables in firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a webapp for voting purposes of a facebook group. I am planning to sign in with facebook and then check if the userid belongs to the group and also if he has not already voted, he can vote.
I am planning on using two databases.
1. Users- {Userid, Status, Date}
This table contains the list of all users currently in group.
2. Votes- {Cid, Cname, NoofVotes}
To tabulate the vote for each candidate.
How do you insert this tables into firebase.
Users is a csv file that i already have with list of all members of the group.
I have experience in SQL, so currently i am confused about firebase database structure.

Comment: I recommend watching the [Firebase Database for SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o) series on Youtube

Comment: Firebase provides a NoSQL database, so most of your SQL knowledge will need to be adapter. For example: there are no tables, and often: tabular structures are not the best way to store data in Firebase. In addition to the video series Rosário recommends, I'd also read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).